# How to set URL when a wiki site is created programmatically in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am creating a new site with:

```
SPSite currentContext = SPContext.GetContext(HttpContext.Current).Site;
SPWeb parentID = currentContext.OpenWeb(new Guid(parentSiteValue));

newWeb = parentID.Webs.Add(newSiteUrl, newSiteName, null, (uint)1033, siteTemplate, true, false);
```

siteTemplate is a template I select in a dropdown and it works fine to create sites when I create a site from a team site template or similiar but when a wiki site is created the actual URL is /pages/home.aspx under the parent site but if I add this to newSiteUrl I get errors such as can't have trailing slash, the folder doesn't exist and so on.

How can I create a wiki site and set the url programmatically?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**
set the URL to 
newSiteUrl = newSiteName + "/pages/"
gives me

```
"testpage/pages/" contains leading or trailing slash, which is invalid.
```

newSiteUrl = newSiteName + "/pages"

```
The folder that would hold URL '/dept/class/wikitest/pages' 
does not exist on the server.
```

newSiteUrl = newSiteName + "/pages/home.aspx"

```
The URL '/dept/class/wikitest/pages/home.aspx' is invalid. 
It may refer to a nonexistent file or folder, 
or refer to a valid file or folder that is not in the current Web.
```

Answer (score 0):

I've posted an answer to your question here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/e25f10ef-bdd9-4445-8508-67b58c2396f9 hope this helps!

### joel

joelblogs.co.uk

Comment: Hi Joel, it says "Replies: 1" on your link but I can't see any, are you editing it?

Comment: Is it something like create the wiki as usual and then change the navigation node for the parent site?

Answer (score 0):

you may set the url in this way:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://localhost"))
{
    string parentWebName = "MyOrganization";
    using (SPWeb parentWeb = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        string webTitle = "DepartMent Wiki";
        string webDesc = "DepartMent Wiki";     string webName = "HRWiki";
        string webUrl = String.Format("{0}/{1}", parentWebName, webName);
        uint webLcid = parentWeb.Language;

        // Name value for the Document Workspace template.
        string webTemplateName = "STS#4";

        SPWeb newWeb = null;

        // Create the new web.
        try
        {
            newWeb = site.AllWebs.Add(webUrl, webTitle, webDesc, webLcid, webTemplateName, false, false);

            SPFolder rootFolder = newWeb.RootFolder; 
            rootFolder.WelcomePage = "My Wiki Library/MyWelcome.aspx";
            rootFolder.Update();
        }
        catch (ArgumentException ex)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

hope this help.